# How do I get a list of programs that can be installed?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt-get

On Linux Mint, where can I find a list of programs that can be installed using `sudo apt-get install (name)` ?

Comment: http://packages.linuxmint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

- use the program `synaptic` (check the application menu) to list and install/remove programs in a graphical user interface
- use the Mint Software Center (check the applications menu)
- use the `apt-cache` command to search from the command line

The list is *long*, so you may want to search it rather than just print it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can open Synaptic Package Manager to view installed, uninstalled, and upgradeable packages:

```
sudo synaptic
```

If it isn't installed, then do:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-cache pkgnames
```

Or type `apt-get install` and then <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice (this depends on how you've set up completion though and takes a while).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Synaptic package manager application that is installed.
It will allow you to see what is installed and what can be installed.

Other wise you can type

```
sudo apt-get install
```

and then push tab a few times. It will ask if you want to list all the packages. There will be thousands.